# Ignoring excluded images in the query

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have this query, it is not written by me and I'm not very good at PHP and Magento and one of my clients who has several images in some products, lets say, there are 14 images, but half of them are excluded and they don't want to show them. So my query returns all pictures for each product. You can see the code below:

```
$_mediaGalleryData = $_read->fetchAll('SELECT
            main.entity_id, `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`,
            `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, `value`.`disabled`, `value`.`label` AS `label_default`,
            `value`.`position` AS `position_default`,
            `value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
            INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value`
                ON main.value_id=value.value_id AND value.store_id=' . $store_id . '
        WHERE (
            value.disabled = 0
            AND main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ')
            AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($collection->getAllIds()) . '))
        ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, value.position, value.position) ASC
    ');
```

But still I'm getting excluded images in this query. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show some of the returned records which should have been excluded